# How to register an item to the SELECT button in Pokemon Fire Red?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

I've heard there is a method to do this in Pokemon FireRed, but I just cannot figure it out.

When you press the SELECT key an nothing is bound, you get prompted:

> An item in the BAG can be registered to SELECT for easy use.

But how exactly do you do this?

I tried pressing the SELECT button in the bag, but this just gives you the ability sort the items, it doesn't bind them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out relatively fast.

I found some instructions in the help menu:

> You may "REGISTER" a **key item** for instant use by pressing SELECT!
>
> 1. Open the "KEY ITEMS" pocket
> 2. Select the key item, then select "REGISTER"

It appears my problem arrised when I wanted to bind a item that was not a "key item".